# Error: Can't convert from `weights` <double> to <integer> due to loss of precision with Histogram

Tags: r, error-handling, histogram, percentage

I'm trying to create a histogram. I have a dataframe which has two columns - one for size and one for the frequency that each size occurs at (in %). In a previous question on here I had issues with just putting `hist(data.frame)` and getting the error >Error in hist.default(CRUST) : 'x' must be numeric.

I was given the solution to use this code:

`data.frame%>% uncount(freq) %>% unlist() %>% hist()`

which worked on my original dataframe (where the frequencies were straight frequencies not %frequencies - I decided to do %freq instead)

However with this new dataframe even though both columns are numeric I get this error message

> Error: Can't convert `weights`  to .
> Backtrace:

1. data.frame %>% uncount(freq) %>% unlist() %>% hist()
2. tidyr::uncount(., freq)
3. vctrs::vec_cast(w, integer(), x_arg = "weights")
4. vctrs::vec_default_cast(...)
5. vctrs::stop_incompatible_cast(...)
6. vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
7. vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
8. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)

just wondering why this may be and how I might be able to fix it

Thanks!

Comment: I think the first comment to your previous question was a good solution and the second comment, not so much.

Comment: You don’t need to make a histogram here since you all ready have a table of frequency vs category. You want to make a column or bar chart. `barplot(freq ~ x, data=df)`